# The following assertion was thrown building ReusableCard(dirty): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a BMI Calculator in Flutter by Angela Yu. My code is generating this error, I quiet do not understand. The error is somewhere in the first Row of the `InputPage widget` I'll appreciate any help.
This is the error message.

```
The following assertion was thrown building ReusableCard(dirty):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

Some more error message is below.

```
This InputPage widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: InputPage
  state: _InputPageState#8c2a5
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: ReusableCard
  dirty
```

ReusableCard widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
      final Color color;
      final Widget cardChild;
      final Function onPress;
    
      const ReusableCard({
        super.key,
        required this.color,
        this.cardChild = const SizedBox(),
        required this.onPress,
      });
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: onPress(),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              height: 205.0,
              width: 175.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // color: Color(0xFF1D1E33),
                color: color,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: cardChild,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

InputPage widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'reusable_card.dart';
import 'icon_content.dart';

const double bottomContainerHeight = 93.0;
const activeCardColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const inactiveCardColor = Color(0xFF111328);
const bottomContainerColor = Color(0xFFEB1555);

enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InputPage> createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Gender selectedGender = Gender.male;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'BMI CALCULATOR',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              ReusableCard(
                onPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedGender = Gender.male;
                  });
                },
                color: selectedGender == Gender.male
                    ? activeCardColor
                    : inactiveCardColor,
                cardChild: const IconContent(icon: Icons.male, label: 'MALE'),
              ),
              ReusableCard(
                onPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedGender = Gender.female;
                  });
                },
                color: selectedGender == Gender.female
                    ? activeCardColor
                    : inactiveCardColor,
                cardChild:
                    const IconContent(icon: Icons.female, label: 'FEMALE'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              ReusableCard(
                onPress: () {},
                color: activeCardColor,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is from `onTap: onPress()`, it is calling the method during build time.

You can use `VoidCallback` on `ReusableCard` instead of function.

```dart
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final VoidCallback onPress; // this

  const ReusableCard({
    super.key,
    required this.color,
    this.cardChild = const SizedBox(),
    required this.onPress,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: onPress, // * 
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          height: 205.0,
          width: 175.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            // color: Color(0xFF1D1E33),
            color: color,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: cardChild,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, your method worked. Thank you @Yeasin Sheikh.

Comment: glad to help, you can also use Function like `onTap:()=> onPress()` but creating another anonymous function feel unnecessary for this case

Comment: Copied that. Thank you. Would like to know how you learnt Flutter.

Comment: I will suggest first to follow dart.dev to learn about dart and then flutter.dev for flutter. You can follow [flutter_roadmap](https://github.com/olexale/flutter_roadmap) and [flutter-developer-roadmap/](https://plugfox.dev/flutter-developer-roadmap/)